# UML Generalization and Relationships

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, diagram

Currently we have a structure like the following in our UML Class Diagram:

```
Node --1------------*-- Data
 ^                        ^
 |                        |
SpecialNode--1----*--SpecialData
```

E.g. SpecialNode is a specialization of the class Node and SpecialData is a specialization of the class Data.

The idea is that each SpecialNode only has SpecialData, and no 'normal' Data.
However, some would argue that since a SpecialNode is a Node, it can have relationships to both Data and SpecialData.

Is there any reference material available that would clarify if SpecialNode can have only SpecialData? If not, how could we inforce this (in a clean way).

Kind Regards,
Joos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, such modeling implies that `SpecialNode` inherits all the properties of `Node`, including `Data`. Otherwise it would contradict the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is an important rule for good design. I would suggest not to define your `Node` and `SpecialNode` as "having" `Data` or `SpecialData` but rather **have an interface to** `Data`. For `Node` it will be associated with `Data` object and for `SpecialNode` it will be associated with `SpecialData` object.